# How to increase Crystal Report's object dynamically

Tags: object, crystal-reports, formula, show-hide

I am working with crystal reports 10.5 and I have a scenario where I need to hide a column(Header, Detail Section, Footers), I did by using suppress formula but can't increase the left or right most column's "Width".
Below I am attaching Crystal Report's version and also the scenario.

[image]

[image]

Comment: A sad work-around would be to create two detail sections. One with the "surcharge" column, the other without it. Then you suppress one or another (and two header sections).

Answer (score 0):

There's only an option to set the `X`-Position inside the `Size and Position` options of the field dynamically.

The measurement is twips (a twip is defined as being 1/1440 of an inch) and if adjusted via formula, the value sets the position relatively to the actual position of the field inside the section.

To achieve what you want you can do a workaround like @heringer already mentioned.
But you could also only just put the field two times inside the details-section with different width and suppress one or another instead of creating two detail-sections.